# Understanding computed properties (square brackets)

Tags: javascript

I simply can't wrap my head around "computed properties", I have googled around but it didn't help much, [the website I am following](http://javascript.info/object) says this, but could anyone make it clearer? I know it's spelled out to me but I still couldn't really understand what it's trying to tell me. Could you try to say it in "simple words"?

> We can use square brackets in an object literal. That’s called
>   *computed properties*.
>
> For instance:
>
> ```
> let fruit = prompt("Which fruit to buy?", "apple");
>
> let bag = {
>   [fruit]: 5, // the name of the property is taken from the variable fruit
> };
>
> alert( bag.apple ); // 5 if fruit="apple"
> ```
>
> The meaning of a computed property is simple: `[fruit]` means that the
>   property name should be taken from `fruit`.
>
> So, if a visitor enters `"apple"`, the `bag` will become `{apple: 5}`.

The part I can't understand is the

```
alert( bag.apple ); // 5 if fruit="apple"
```

Comment: Can you please provide the direct link to the page from where you quoted the text?

Comment: What is unclear about this? If you used `{ fruit: 5 }`, then the key would be `fruit`, no matter whether a variable named `fruit` existed or not - because that is a _text literal_ at this point. So if you want to specify the key _dynamically_, you either need to use this syntax, or `bag[fruit] = 5` (in that case the `bag` would need to exist prior to that line.)

Comment: They could have used `let fruit = "apple"` without the prompt, but they wanted to explicitly make the variable value dynamic.

Comment: @Bergi http://javascript.info/object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're saving the value of the `prompt` in a variable called `fruit`. In this case, it defaults to "apple".

You're then declaring another variable, `bag`. `bag` has one property, which here is `[fruit]`. This will evaluate to the value of `fruit` at runtime, effectively making the declaration

```
let bag = {
  'apple': 5
};
```

The alert function will then alert the value of `bag.apple`. `bag.apple` has a value because you set `bag[fruit]` to be 5 when you declared the `bag` variable, and `fruit` is `'apple'`.

Comment: relevant article : https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/javascript-object-creation-356e504173a8

Answer (score 0):

javascript is different in this as in Python
`d={xx:11}`
d set to be `{ xx: 11 }` 
Now

```
key="we"
d={[key]:22}
```

d1 set to be `{ we: 22 }` Python would not accept xx - it would be not-defined. But js will see xx as a string 'xx'. If you want to use it the Python way, you have to use [key]:22 as in above.

Answer (score 0):

The visitor doesn't have to enter "apple". It was supplied as the default in the prompt. Only by modifying the alert: alert(bag[fruit]) could the user enter a different value in the prompt, e.g., "banana" and get the alert to report 5 instead of undefined. I use computed values mostly for returning an iterator from an iterable function:

```
let interator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
```

, and object keys that have spaces or characters that don't conform to the production for a JavaScript identifier.