# In Node.js and Mongoose, how can I use a variable in place of a model name?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a couple of collections with tons of documents, like "all books in the world" and "all movies in the world." To reduce the size of my collections and because there are so many unique properties between the two, I have them as separate collections.

But I have a lot of Node.js functions where the only difference between two functions is the model I am querying on. I would like to make more generic functions to reduce the amount of code.

To greatly simplify the example, I currently have this:

```
import { Book, Movie } from '../models'

const getBooks = (bookId) => Book.findById(bookId)
const getMovies = (movieId) => Movie.findById(movieId)
```

And I would like to be able to do something like this, where type would be either 'Book' or 'Movie':

```
import { Book, Movie } from '../models'
const getItems = (type, itemId) => type.findById(itemId)
```

I have tried all kinds of things, but the only thing I can get to work is having ternary operators all over the place (which will probably become switch statements when I add additional collections).

Is there a more elegant way of doing this? And if so, recommended? Or does this just point to schema design issues?

This would kind of be like using computed properties, but not for the name of a property, but for the name of the object itself. This does not seem to work"

```
import { Book, Movie } from '../models'
const getItems = (type, itemId) => [type].findById(itemId)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding computed properties (square brackets)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47052938/understanding-computed-properties-square-brackets)

Comment: "computed properties" is the Javascript language feature which allows you to use variable values as object keys.  in your case you would set the value of a hypothetical `mediaType` variable (or whatever) to e.g. `Book` or `Movie`.

Comment: @DanO - I am using computed properties as part of my solution already. But in this case the model is not a property, it is the object itself. Correct? Computed properties allow you to do iceCream[name] = 'vanilla', but const food = 'iceCream' [food].name = 'vanilla' does not seem to work for me.

Comment: Isn't it possible to just pass the collection's class as argument to the `getItems` method? I haven't tested this otherwise I'd post this as an answer since I believe this should work.

Comment: @Meiogordo - If I am following your correctly, I am not sure how that would help or work. If you could provide a code example, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: When you call `getItems` will `type` be the string name of the type, or will it be an instance of `Model`?

Comment: @gregg My suggestion was similar to the accepted answer, but without the need for a map. You can just pass the type itself as argument. Basically calling the `getItems` method you specified like `getItem(Book, 1)`. In which `Book` is `import { Book, Movie } from '../models'`

Comment: I think that the OP tried that solution and didn't work. Whether it worked or not, I think that by passing the model as a parameter you lose some encapsulation. Think that you are now importing your models from outside of your database access layer instead of using an interface to decouple the mongoose model from your business logic.

Comment: @iromano97 I agree with the issue of loss of encapsulation. However, having to have the strings mapped out to objects seems like a bit pointless, since you are creating an association just to get the model again. Whenever you need to consider a new model you need to update this mapping as well.
OP was also not clear if this would be used in different files or if the "loss of encapsulation" would be an issue even.

Comment: @Meiogordo I agree with the pointless of the string mapping. I'll update the answer with the pros and cons of both solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could pass the type as the string name of your collection and the number of models doesn't grow every day (if that is not the case you should be always updating the `myModels` object) the following solution should do the job

```js
import { Book, Movie } from '../models'

const myModels = {
    book: Book,
    movie: Movie,
};

const getItems = (type, itemId) => myModels[type].findById(itemId)
```

I would suggest doing something if there's a chance that the type passed as a parameter cannot exist.

---

**EDIT**

As mentioned via comments by @Meiogordo mapping the Models against the strings would be pointless if you are not going to use the functions outside the data access layer.

```js
import { Book, Movie } from '../models';

const getItems = (model, itemId) => model.findById(itemId);

const book = getItems(Book, 1);
const movie = getItems(Movie, 3);
```

With this solution, you lose some encapsulation due to the need for requiring the models outside the data access layer, but you are not mapping the models on a separated structure.

Comment: As mentioned in this answer, note that if the key is not defined, `myModels[type]` will be `undefined` and thus the method call will result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed via comments, this should work for your use-case:

```js
// Defining the function
const getItems = (model, itemId) => model.findById(itemId)

// And assuming this import
imports { Book, Movie } from '../models';

// You can just call it like so
const book_one = getItems(Book, 1);
const movie_three = getItems(Movie, 3);
```

The first argument to `getItems` can just be the Model class itself.